# What is an “estate,” as in a “housing estate” or “council estate”?

Tags: legal-terms, common-law, trusts-and-estates, any-jurisdiction

Also, how does this sense of the word differ from those used in other jurisdictions, and how are any of the senses of the term derived from one another if at all?

Comment: This is basically an English dialectology question. In East Africa it basically means "housing development", it's rarely used that way in the US, instead it refers to the property of a dead person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is an “estate,” as in a “housing estate” or “council estate”?

See [*Oxford English Dictionary*: "housing, *n.1*"](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/88956):

> **housing estate** *n. British* a residential area in which the houses, streets, etc., have all been planned and built at the same time.

And see ["council, *n.*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/42589):

> **council estate**, *n.* (also **council housing estate**) a group of houses erected by a council