# What did Arden LJ mean by "estate", in "legal estate in the shares" of an unlimited corporation?

Tags: legal-terms, property, ownership, trusts-and-estates, equity

I am baffled by Arden  LJ (as she then was) at para. 59 in [*Pennington & Anor v Waine & Ors* [2002] EWCA Civ 227](http://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWCA/Civ/2002/227.html).

> So, too, in *Re Rose, Rose v IRC* the Court of Appeal held that the beneficial interest in the shares passed when the share transfers were delivered to the transferee, and that consequently the transferor was a trustee of the **legal estate in the shares [emphasis added]** from that date.

I quote Evershed MR in [*Rose, Re* [1952] EWCA Civ 4](http://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWCA/Civ/2002/227.html).

> On the 30th March, 1943, one Eric Hamilton Rose (since deceased) executed two transfers of shares in a company known as the Leweston Estates Company. That company, as its name implies, was an unlimited corporation.

I am not a lawyer. I have seen Estate in just three contexts. The first is in Real Estate. Second is [housing Estate](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/93983). Third is [Free Hold and Lease Hold](https://www.foxtons.co.uk/discover/2022/09/leasehold-vs-freehold-the-differences-and-what-to-consider) Estates.

[image]

#### But none these contexts appertain to *Re Rose*! What the deuce is a "legal estate in the shares" of a corporation? How can you have legal Estate in corporate shares??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a use of the term "estate" to simply mean something like "extent of property interest." It is not a common use, and somewhat archaic, but not unheard of.

The distinction being made is between the *equitable* interest and the *legal* interest in the shares.

I have not read the case, but from the excerpt, it seems like Arden LJ was describing a scenario where the beneficial interest in the shares had moved to the transferee, but the legal interest (estate) remained with the transferor, albeit in trust for the transferee/beneficiary.

Comment: Thanks, but what does "extent of property interest" mean? Please explain in layman terms, in plain English.